# Youtube and other apps not showing on Android 11 emulator

Tags: java, android, youtube

I have downloaded android Q(API level 29) and R(API level 30) on avd manager also on two virtual devices. The difference is that when i am running an app on android Q which is API level 29 , youtube and other google native apps are showing in the emulator. But when i am running android R(API level 30) youtube and google native apps are not showing.How i can resolve it please help.

Comment: Did you use the "Google Play" edition of the emulator images? If not, try that. If you did, then perhaps Google did not bundle those apps with the API Level 30 Google Play emulator image.

Comment: Where i can find it ?

Comment: I am not certain what "it" is. If you mean the Google Play emulator images, whatever exists is available in the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanks got it. I changed the device from AVD manager and download the image on virtual device which have playstore by default.